# Using the output of grep, to grep another string/strings in a different file in the same directory

Tags: grep

There are 2 files in a directory.
simv.log, and config.txt

simv.log contains the string "test failed".
config.txt contains the following strings:-
width
height

I know how to grep for "test failed" in simv.log.
However, if simv.log contains "test failed", I wish to grep for "width" and/or "height" in config.txt.

How do I do this?
Do you need to use awk and/or sed for this? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this chain 2 greps with the && condition. In the first grep, the resulting line is suppressed by piping to /dev/null but the return code is used to run the second grep or not:

```
grep "test failed" simv.log >/dev/null && egrep 'width|height' config.txt
```

outputs

```
width=10 
height=12
```

but

```
grep "test failed" otherlog.log >/dev/null && egrep 'width|height' config.txt
```

does not list the width and height